How can I update days of week in vue2?
I am new to VueJs. I have this modal:
  <b-modal
    :id="`Rel${object.id}`"
    ref="editModal"
    title="Update data"
    centered
    hide-footer
    :myobject="object"
  >
    <form class="needs-validation" @submit.prevent="handleEdit(object)">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <label class="mt-3">Days</label>
        {{ weekdaySelected }}
        <multiselect
          required
          v-model="weekdaySelected"
          :options="weekdayOptions"
          track-by="id"
          label="weekday"
          multiple
          placeholder="Choose day"
          selectLabel="Choose day"
          selectedLabel="Chose"
        >
        </multiselect>
      </div>
    </form>
  </b-modal>

And this is the method that edits the data:
handleEdit(row) {
  if (this.timesAreValid(row.start_time, row.end_time, row.is_night_shift)) {
    const data = { ...row };
    console.log("My data: ", data);
    console.log("My weekdays before update: ", data.weekdays);
    // data.weekdays=this.weekdaySelected.map(day=>day.id);
    this.weekdaySelected = data.weekdays;
    console.log("My weekdays: ", data.weekdays);
    console.log("Initial selected weekdays: ", this.weekdaySelected);
    // delete data.weekdays;
    this.weekdaySelected = row.weekdays;
    console.log("Selected weekdays: ", this.weekdaySelected);
    data.weekdays = row.weekdays.map((e) => {
      return { id: e, weekday: e - 1 };
    });
    console.log("My new weekdays: ", data.weekdays);
    session
      .put(`api/user/schedule/${row.id}/update/`, data)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data);
        this.$toastr.Add({
          name: "UniqueToastName",
          title: `Update`,
          msg: "Schedule updated",
          style: { backgroundColor: "#4fd69c", width: "550px" },
          progressbar: false,
          timeout: 3501,
        });

        console.log("Row: ", row);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.$bvModal.hide(`Rel${row.id}`);
        }, 1000);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        this.$toastr.e(`Error : ${JSON.stringify(e)}  `);
      });
  } else {
    this.$toastr.e("End hour should be after start hour");
  }
}


My problem is that data is saved to weekdaySelected in row at this.weekdaySelected=data.weekdays; but when I press the edit button the data doesn't appear in the placeholder.
How can I update the days of the week to make it show up in the placeholder?

You need to create a reproducible example, so that it would be easier to help, try creating a codepen or code-sandbox link. Are you have any specific error in console, and what the console log prints?

I don't have error in console.log. My problem is that the days are not updated

See How to Ask and provide minimal, reproducible example.  We're not shown how variables are initially defined (what is weekdayOptions? Where does row data come from)? It's not minimal either, e.g. where is the button calling the method? lines like $toastr code can probably be removed. Does it matter that the code is in a modal? etc...
